# Filling a text field in a php form field with passed URL data

Tags: php, forms, get

I'm trying to fill the following form field with info passed from a form via url. I just can't seem to make it work. My PHP is super limited.

This is the url:
`https://www.example.com/membership-account/?level=1&course=Online%20Membership`

And this is the text field I'm trying to fill in the php form

```
$fields[] = new Form_Field("Course", "text", array(
    "size" => 40,
    "class" => "Course",
    "profile" => true,
    "required" => true
));
```

I'm presuming I need to put `$_GET['course']` in there somewhere, but wherever I place it, it just doesn't seem to work. Maybe there is more code required than simply including a the `$_GET` function?

**Additional Information:**

Mohans addition of the GET function works, however removing 'text' means the field type is not defined so where the field should be, it instead reads - "Unknown type **Online Membership** for field **Course**." Including 'text' where it was originally, for some reason prevents $_GET from working??

So I guess the question now is, how do I get 'text' and $_GET to work together??

**Additional Information:**

Could the $_GET be placed as a value in the array? I've tried putting:

`"text" => $_GET['course']`
or
`"course" => $_GET['course']`
But neither work.. I'm probably thinking about it the wrong way.

Any help at this point would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```php
 $fields[] = new Form_Field("Course", trim($_GET['course']), array(
        "size" => 40,
        "class" => "Course",
        "profile" => true,
        "required" => true
    ));
```

Comment: Mohan, thanks very much for the reply!!

It seems to be populating the field as intended however the field is filled with.. "Unknown type Online Membership for field Course." I guess this is because "text" has been taken out of the code?? I tried putting it back in, but then it doesn't work :(